# Jscript errors when embedded in XSLT - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, xslt-1.0, jscript

I've written a JavaScript function which passed testing on all inputs when run in Node.js. However it is now causing a runtime error when it's embedded into an XSLT template (parsed using MS XML). Error message below:-

```
COM+ Msg = Microsoft JScript runtime error
Object doesn't support this property or method
line = 47, col = 5 (line is offset from the start of the script block).
Error returned from property or method call.
```

The line number in the error message corresponds to the closing bracket of the JScript function.

Code below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://www.stylusstudio.com/file-utilities">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    
    <msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
        <![CDATA[
            function TrimmedString(inString) {
                var stringArray = inString.split(' ');
                var keyword;
                /*logic omitted here assigns phrase to trim before in inString - assigned to keyword, blank if phrase doesn't exist*/
            
                if (keyword !== '') {
                    var outString = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
                        if (i !== 0) {
                            outString += " ";
                        }
                        else if (stringArray[i].indexOf(keyword) == -1) {
                            outString += stringArray[i];
                        }
                        else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return TrimmedString(outString.toString());
                }
                else {
                    return inString.trim();
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="user:TrimmedString(string(/XML_ParentNode/XML_ChildNode/@AttributeContainingString))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the error first arose, I removed all instances of string.includes() and replaced them with string.indexOf() !== -1, I also replaced all ES6 specific functionality from the embedded JScript. This seemed to resolve issues highlighted to a specific line, but now that it's triggering on the final bracket I'm out of ideas. The message is also confusing as the input parameter is always a string, and all methods used below are fairly vanilla methods for the string object type.

Is there a method here which isn't supported when run by XSLT? The script itself was fine when I tested it as a standalone piece of code on Node.js.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: `line = 47, col = 5` - the code isn't that long ... perhaps it's `.trim()`? I mean, if a string doesn't have `.includes()` it probably won't have `.trim()` either

Comment: @Bravo sorry, the error message used includes code which was replaced by the comment at line 4 of the JScript element. Removing .trim() resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Bravo pointed out in the comments to try removing .trim() from the return command. So it looks like this method is not supported when embedded in an XSLT template. Thanks!

Comment: `Microsoft JScript` is based on a very old specification of javascript (I mean, it's called jscript, not javascript) - back when microsoft thought they could rewrite the internet for themselves :p